# Cancel in Facebook login throwing java.lang.RunTimeException telling sdks is not initialised

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am having difficulties using Facebook login in my app. This is happening when user press cancel when authorising my app when login for the first time using the native installed app in handset.

**As my app's login place was in a fragment so what I did was to send the control to another activity when user click on login and from there on, I do all callbacks. I programmatically clicked the button to get the call back**

I am initialising the app through the below code

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookVirtualActivity.this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook_virtual);

loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        Log.v("ONMESSAGE", "Data Arived");
}
        @Override
        public void onCancel(LoginResult loginResult) {
        Log.v("ONMESSAGE", "Login cancelled");
}
```

Now when user cancel the login, I get the below stack trace

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=129742, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.release.goquest/com.facebook.FacebookActivity}: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.

I am not sure whether this has to do with initialisation or not cause, pressing confirm is returning data.

Comment: Are you using facebook LoginButton ?

Comment: Yes, I show a Facebook button, then I take the user to a virtual activity, there is also a Facebook login button, which I programatically called to get the callback!!

Comment: can you show how you initialize your CallbackManager

Comment: Thanks for the patience. I made the callbackmanager a instance variable and then I initialise using the below code

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

Answer (score 1):

Update :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button facebook;
    private LoginManager loginManager;
    private CustomFacebookCallback callback;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Facebook initialize
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(MainActivity.this);
        FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.GRAPH_API_DEBUG_INFO);
        FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.DEVELOPER_ERRORS);
        FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
        FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_RAW_RESPONSES);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Init button
        facebook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.facebook);

        // Instantiate parts and variables
        callback = new CustomFacebookCallback();

        // Callback Manager initialize
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        //===================
        // Facebook Login
        //===================

        // 1) Permissions
        final ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        permissions.add("email");
        permissions.add("public_profile");
        permissions.add("user_friends");

        // 2) Set login function to button
        facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
                loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissions);
                loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
            }
        });
    }

    private class CustomFacebookCallback implements FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d("Facebook", "Success!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("Facebook", "Canceled!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.e("Facebook", "Error!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

The above code is working with `onCancel()` called. You may try refer to it.

Comment: As I did call to callback manager in Activity and get data there only, I did not  do onActivityResult in my fragment because I send control to Activity!!!

Comment: I have updated the answer. Since you are not giving full code, it is hard for me to debug. Hope you can solve your problem with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You **must** call LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions() from **Activity**. It doesn't matter where you initilize facebook sdk and set registerCallback method. Even you initilize facebook sdk and set registerCallback in fragment, you must call LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions() in Activity. Otherwise, request code will be 129472 and you never catch facebook login result.